# How to add create an entity inside another entity (NestJS)?

Tags: javascript, rest, controller, backend, nestjs

I have two entities: User and Photo with relationship OneToMany. One user can have many photos.
User:

```
@Entity('users')
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;

  @Exclude()
  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  avatar: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Photo, photo => photo.user, { cascade: true })
  photos: Photo[];
}
```

And Photo:

```
@Entity('photos')
export class Photo {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  url: string;

  @Column({default: ""})
  description: string;
  
  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.photos)
  user: User;
}
```

So, my question is: how can i add new photo to specific user? I tried to do something like this, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
@Patch(':id/photos')
  addPhoto(@Param('id') id: number, @Body() createPhotoDto: CreatePhotoDto){
    return this.userService.createImage(id, createPhotoDto);
  }



async createImage(id: number, createPhotoDto: CreatePhotoDto) {
    const user = await this.usersRepository.findOne(id);
    const newUser = await this.usersRepository.preload({
      id: +id,
      photos: [...user.photos, createPhotoDto]
    });

    return this.usersRepository.save(newUser);
  }
```

Comment: can you share you createPhotoDto?

Comment: @Youba 
export class CreatePhotoDto {
    url: string
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I got from the CreatePhotoDto that you save the image and bind it with the user,
*one of the easiest way to do it*, First declare you imageRepository in your service then :

```
    async createImage(id: number, createPhotoDto: CreatePhotoDto) {
     const user = await this.usersRepository.findOne(id);
      
     return   await this.imageRepository.save({url:createPhotoDto.url,user:user});
    // if you want to return the user with the image added you make another find with the relation  exp:
   //  return  await this.usersRepository.findOne(id,{ relations: ['photos'],});
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. But what is the hard way? And which one is better?

Comment: I just used 'easiest way' to describe this solution as a cleaner one, as you see we did it in one line from imageRepository side not the user one